# What does "cpu_time" represent exactly in libvirt?

Tags: virtualization, kvm, libvirt

I can pull the following CPU values from libvirt:

```
virsh domstats vm1 --cpu-total
Domain: 'vm1'
  cpu.time=6173016809079111
  cpu.user=26714880000000
  cpu.system=248540680000000

virsh cpu-stats vm1 --total
Total:
    cpu_time       6173017.263233824 seconds
    user_time        26714.890000000 seconds
    system_time     248540.700000000 seconds
```

What does the cpu_time figure represent here exactly?

I'm looking to calculate CPU utilization as a percentage using this data.

Thanks

Answer (score 40):

This was a surprisingly difficult question to answer! After pouring over the kernel code for a good while I've figured out what's going on here and its quite nice to learn what's going on.

Normally for a process on Linux, the overall CPU usage is simply the sum of the time spent in userspace and the time spent on kernel space. So naively one would have expected `user_time + system_time` to equal `cpu_time`. What I've discovered is that Linux tracks time spent by vCPU threads executing guest code separately from either userspace or kernelspace time.

Thus `cpu_time == user_time + system_time + guest_time`

So you can think of `system_time + user_time` as giving the overhead of QEMU / KVM on the host side. And `cpu_time - (user_time + system_time)` as giving the actual amount of time the guest OS was running its CPUs.

To calculate CPU usage, you probably just want to record `cpu_time` every N seconds and calculate the delta between two samples. eg `usage % = 100 * (cpu_time 2 - cpu_time 1) / N`

Comment: Fanastic answer in my opinion!

Comment: If anyone ends up here looking at the CPU time given from the virNodeGetCPUStats function in libvirt, make sure you divide by nanoseconds since the time there is in nanoseconds. :)

Answer (score 1):

As per master pulled 2018-07-10 from https://github.com/libvirt/libvirt/ and as far as QEMU/KVM is concerned, it comes down to:

- `cpu.time` = `cpuacct.usage` cgroup metric
- `cpu.{user,system}` = `cpuacct.stat` cgroup metrics

Problem one may encounter is `guest load = time load - system load - user load` sometime leads to negative values (?!?), example given for a running QEMU/KVM guest (values are seconds), with Debian 9 stock kernel (4.9):

```
time                   system    user     total
2018-07-10T13:19:20Z 62308.67 9278.59 107968.33
2018-07-10T13:20:20Z 62316.08 9279.73 107970.73
               delta     7.41    1.14      2.40 (2.40 < 7.41+1.14 ?!?)
```

Kernel bug ? (at least one person experiments something similar: https://lkml.org/lkml/2017/11/1/101)
One thing is certain: `cpuacct.usage` and `cpuacct.stat` do use a different logic to gather their metrics; this might explain the discrepancy (?).

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the above answers are NOT correct in the CPUACCT controller for a KVM guest:

```
cpu_time == user_time + system_time + guest_time (<-- wrong)
```

If you run a CPU-intensive benchmark compared to an I/O or network-intensive benchmark in the VM, you'll see that "guest time" does not match up in the formula.

Guest time (according to /proc/< pid >/stat) represents ONLY the time used by the VCPUs to run the guest virtual machine (While not exiting or handling I/O).

The CPUACCT controller's *top-level parent directory* for each KVM/libvirt guest **includes** both the time spent on the "emulator" and "vcpuX" sub-directories **in their totality**, including vhost kernel threads and non-VCPU pthreads running inside the QEMU main process, not just guest time or user/system time.

That makes the above formula wrong. The correct formula would be:

```
guest_time = sum(vcpuX)=>cpu.time - sum(vcpuX)=>(for each child: cpuacct.stat=>user + cpuacct.stat=>system)
```

You cannot simply use the top-level parent files to calculate guest time. That would be totally inaccurate under any I/O bound workload.